# How to solve this "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

[![Message error]]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciKCK.png

My point is if someone go to Authorize page without login, It will be redirected to the login page.

This is my code (.NET Core 3.1):

My Controller

```cs
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Username()
    {
        var lstUsername = _dbContext.MT_USERNAME.ToList();
        return View(lstUsername);
    }
```

My Startup.cs

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<GPServiceDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(xxx);
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);   
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStatusCodePages(context =>
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ||
                response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                response.Redirect("/Login/Login");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#iisiis-express read this article.you could add others authentication schemes refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2xfor more details .

Answer (score 6):

In my case there was just a simple error on authentication options parameter

```
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme
```

instead of this:

```
options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Without this, even if I returned `Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail` and set response code to `401`, the exception was thrown and 500 was returned. Do you have any idea why this fix works?

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't configure authentication service in ConfigureServices. Take the cookie authentication as an example. An default authenticationScheme need to be specified.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie;
        })
        .AddCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, options =>
        {
            
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
        });

        //...
    }
```

About this, you can also refer to these documents.

[ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thank you Karney. But if I use session this code is still work?

Comment: I got error "The name 'DefaultAuthenticationTypes' does not exist in the current context"
and I use "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;" already.

Comment: @GPService, `DefaultAuthenticationTypes` is part of Identity framework, add a using to the top of the file. `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`